# Trouble understanding piece of code in LISP

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I need some help understanding what this code does. I am not sure what the `fcombine` variable does? Can someone please give me a walkthrough of what the code is doing?

```
(define (reduce fcombine L)
  (cond
    ((null? (cdr L)) (car L))
    (#t (fcombine (car L) (reduce fcombine (cdr L))))))
```

Comment: You could have a look at the CLHS `reduce` function spec here: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm  The function you have shown is a partial implementation of the full spec.

Comment: thank you, can you make that an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Just to note: this is very similar to the definition of the *fold-right* function, except that the initial accumulator here is the last element of the list.  It's essentially a loop that runs across *L*, using *fcombine* to accumulate some result as we visit the individual elements.  This *reduce* function doesn't work on empty lists, so it's a bit less general than *fold-right*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a look at the CLHS [reduce function](http://lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm) spec.

The function you have shown is a partial implementation of the full spec, with just the *function* and *sequence* arguments.

Comment: Note that this isn't a Common Lisp program -- it's a Scheme program, and this is a pretty typical version of `reduce` in Scheme.

Comment: I had recognised it as scheme code :)   See also comment on question from @dyoo which has useful information regarding `fold-*`.